# Must I cross-compile modules if the kernel is cross-compiled?

Tags: linux, arm, raspberry-pi, cross-compiling, kernel-module

I have a cross-compiled Linux kernel, and it works fine on my Raspberry Pi 2. However, when I later compile modules on Raspberry Pi itself, error is reported.

After googling, the reason of this problem seems due to the cross-compiling which makes some tools located in `linux/scripts/` are not suitable for arm architecture but X86.

I am not sure that whether it is necessary to compile modules on PC if the kernel is cross-compiled. If not, how could I transfer these tools to Pi?

Answer (score 2):

**No**. That would be unusual and you should expect issues if you try to do that.

Compile the modules where you compiled the kernel (since then you already have the toolchains, and there's much less chance of something breaking due to different versions).

If you cross-compiled the kernel on PC, do the same with modules. If you natively compiled the kernel on RPI, do the same with modules.

Comment: How can I compile kernel on PC and then compile modules on Pi itself?

Comment: @DouglasSu If you have the means to build modules on the device, then surely you already have the right kernel sources, .config, and toolchain on the device. Thus if you can boot a cross-compiled kernel to userspace, you can then rebuild the same kernel natively, install that, and have everything match from then on.

Comment: @Notlikethat I think that is impossible to compile kernel on PC, install and boot this kernel on Pi, and then make new modules with this new kernel. `./scripts/recordmcount` reports error when I compile module.

Comment: I have tired to build kernel and modules directly on Pi, it is fine. Building kernel, however, as you know, is much more time consuming. As compare to compile kernel, compiling simple modules is fast and easy. So I wish that I can compile kernel on PC and compile modules on Pi. But, it seems not working.

Comment: I suggest you actually solve the issue that you have building modules on your PC. Or if you really wish, compile them on RPi. But in any case we'll need much more than "it is not working" to be able to help you with it.